# Connect Zuul CI with GitHub

Tags: github, zuul-ci

I want to connect [Zuul CI](https://zuul-ci.org/) with [GitHub](http://github.com/)

[This page](https://zuul-ci.org/docs/zuul/reference/drivers/github.html) describes how to do it.

The part that I do not understand is:

```
Set Webhook URL to
http://<zuul-hostname>:<port>/api/connection/<connection-name>/payload.
```

What is `<connection-name>` here?

I tried the tenant name here, but this did not work.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connection-name` is the name of the github connection in your `zuul.conf` and can be chosen freely.